# Search for a location in a file based on a number of spaces

Tags: grep

What is the best way to extract the two fields (I have marked them in parenthesis) in the following line on a Linux system.

```
<measResults>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 311133336 325126 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10427349176 3527288 284344 439048 3582 3583 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14422 14422 (311133336) 325126 (10427349176) 3527288 </measResults>
```

This is a single line in a *.xml file.

I am hoping some variant of grep would work but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: grep these numbers based on what exactly ?

Comment: The values I marked in parenthesis are always the same place in the file based on the number of spaces.  I have found that the cut command will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they always at the same position (i.e. after the same amount of spaces)? If so, I would use awk:

```
# echo "$string" | awk '{ print $51 }'
(311133336)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes they are always located the same number of spaces.  I did find the cut -d ' ' -f67,69 also will grab the same data.  Would you recommend awk over cut or would it be a wash?

Comment: awk is more powerful than cut, but probably a bit slower. You can try timing both commands by prepending them with `time`.

Comment: I will.  My command has gotten quite long but it seems to be working.  grep -A12 -h "1526726664" *MY_FILE_NAME.xml | grep "measResults" | cut -d ' ' -f67,69 > MY_FILE_OUTPUT.txt            Thanks!

Comment: You should always double quote variable. `echo "$string"`

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk '{print $51,$53}' <<< "$string"
(311133336) (10427349176)
```